# Esconder elemento somente se estiver visível ou vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando o evento **change** em um campo select, no qual a option correspondente é o id de uma div, o que gostaria de fazer é exibir a div selecionada e esconder as demais somente se esta estiver visível ou oculta, de uma forma dinamica caso uma div que foi ocultada poda ser exibida novamente.

a estrutura basicamente é essa:

```
<select class="form-control" name="template">
   <option value="template1">Template 1</option>
   <option value="template2">Template 2</option>
</select>
<div id="template1">tema 1</div>
<div id="template2">tema 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [`attributeNotEqual`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) ou o método [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

#### attributeNotEqual

```js
$('select[name="template"]').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  // Oculta as DIV's menos a selecionada
  $('div.template[id!="'+id+'"]').hide();
  // Caso a DIV selecionada esteja oculta, exibe
  $('div.template[id="'+id+'"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="template">
   <option value="template1">Template 1</option>
   <option value="template2">Template 2</option>
</select>

<div class="template" id="template1">tema 1</div>
<div class="template" id="template2">tema 2</div>
```

#### :not()

```js
$('select[name="template"]').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  // Oculta as DIV's menos a selecionada
  $('div.template:not([id="'+id+'"])').hide();
  // Caso a DIV selecionada esteja oculta, exibe
  $('div.template[id="'+id+'"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="template">
   <option value="template1">Template 1</option>
   <option value="template2">Template 2</option>
</select>

<div class="template" id="template1">tema 1</div>
<div class="template" id="template2">tema 2</div>
```

Comment: Por algum motivo quando eu seleciono qualquer option a página inteira fica oculta kk

Comment: Se estiver assim: `$('[id!="'+id+'"]').hide();` vai ocultar tudo, deve estar assim: `$('div[id!="'+id+'"]').hide();` informando que o elemento é a `DIV`

Comment: ainda continua, acho que ficou genérica, ele abrange todas as divs

Comment: Veja fiz uma modificação, adicionei o atributo `class`.

Comment: agora sim, obrigado :)